# Entity Framework 4 Returning KEY/Primary Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, primary-key, key

Entity Framework 4 Returning KEY/Primary Key

I’m Trying to find a way to Return a Key/Primary Key without having to create a stored procedure to do it for me using:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserRecords]
(
    @Name   varchar(10)
) AS

-- INSERT the new record
INSERT INTO MyTable (Name)
VALUES(@Name)

-- Now return the InventoryID of the newly inserted record
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID
```

Though Visual Studio 2010 I then Use the **Add Function Import** From the Model Browser and Create a Complex Type.

Then Though C# i use the Following Code to check its working.

```
 SQL_DB_Entities DB= new SQL_DB_Entities();
            var ReturnValue = DB.UserRecords("BOB").First();
            Console.Write(ReturnValue.ID);
            Console.Read();
```

I'm simply looking for a better way to return the ID and also being very sure im not going to cause head aches for myself laster on down the track.

If you feel this is not the best way to return the key please let me know.

I have Tried it this way but returns 0

```
SQL_DB_Entities DB = new SQL_DB_Entities();
User UserObject = new User{Name = “BOB”};
DB.AddToUserTable(UserObject);
DB.SaveChanges(): 
Int key = UserObject.ID;
Console.WriteLine(key.ToString());
```

I should also mention that the DB is looking after the Primary Keys not my application.

Comment: From memory EF will normally select/return the object that is inserted including the PK. I'm not sure why you aren't getting it and if it's the right approach to get the PK explicitly. Why do you need it?

Comment: The last example must work. If it doesn't you misconfigured something.

Comment: @Ladislav and @Ben your both 100% correct thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly setup `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity` in your entity and if you have autogenerated PKs in the database, EF will fill the Ids of your inserted entities after each save changes. Check [this article](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2011/03/the-bug-in-storegeneratedpattern-fixed-in-vs-2010-sp1/) to understand store generated pattern.

Comment: that all works fine but returning the ID of the record that has just been inserted seems to be the issue. I have the StoreGeneratedPattern Set to Identity. This was Automatically Via Visual Studio Update Model From Database.

Comment: @Ches: Now I don't undrestand. You are saying that it works fine but it causes an issue. Can you chek what statements are executed by SQL Profiler?

Comment: My Issue Isnt inserting the Data into the table its returning the ID directly after i have inserted the data. Grabing SQL Profiler details now.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to set the StoreGeneratedPattern property of the PK column in your model as Identity. Or if you are using code-first, annotate the property with:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

I am not sure whether this works with sprocs, though. By the way, any special reason you are using sprocs in this case?

Comment: The Entity Frame picked up that that i had a primary key in the Table and used it as the identity. So that worked straight away.

Comment: Only Using Sprocs as only way i can return the key after a insert

Comment: @Ches. No, using sprocs is not the only way. In your db, mark the column as identity and then set the StoreGeneratedPattern property of the same column in your model to Identity. Entity framework will do the rest. I do this kind thing all the time without a sproc in sight.

Comment: I have the StoreGeneratedPattern set to Identity and i have no issues adding the data. Its returning the Key of what has been Directly Inserted. I have no doubt you are correct. But as of yet i have been unable to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Normally PKs are dealt with as a particular property on an EF Object [EntityKey](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/05/15/setting-an-entityreference-using-an-entitykey-in-entity-framework.aspx). You are probably best to have a look at EntityKeys.